# Why two ip address for only one network card in my pc?

Tags: network-interface, ip

There is only one network card in my pc.

```
lshw -class network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 15
       serial: 
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.10.0-8-amd64 duplex=full ip=192.168.31.43 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:32 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: anbox0
       serial:  
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.250.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: lxcbr0
       serial:  
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=10.0.3.1 link=no multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Show all ip address:

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.31.43/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic enp6s0
       valid_lft 37676sec preferred_lft 37676sec
    inet 192.168.31.42/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global secondary enp6s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e0:70ff:fec2:2e91/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: anbox0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether   brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.250.1/24 scope global anbox0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bce8:93ff:fe88:11c1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: lxcbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether   brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.1/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global lxcbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Why ther are two ip address `192.168.31.43` and `192.168.31.42` in my pc?

Os info:

```
cat  /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l
```

The network configuration file:

```
cat  /etc/network/interfaces
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet dhcp
```

Which ip address is used in my local network?

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.31.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-21 21:41 HKT
Nmap scan report for XiaoQiang (192.168.31.1)
Host is up (0.00026s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.31.42
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.31.43
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 1.98 seconds
```

`192.168.31.1` is a router which connect internet and intranet.

Both two ip `192.168.31.42` and `192.168.31.43` are used at the same time?
Add a new pc into the local network which combined with a simple home router.

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.31.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-21 21:41 HKT
Nmap scan report for XiaoQiang (192.168.31.1)
Host is up (0.00026s latency).
MAC Address:  (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.31.70
Host is up (0.000057s latency).
MAC Address: 00:E0:72:64:2C:19 (Lynk)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.31.42
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.31.43
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 1.98 seconds
```

The new pc's ip is `192.168.31.70`,try to connect from `192.168.31.70` to ``192.168.31.42`and`192.168.31.43`.

```
ssh root@192.168.31.42
ls  /home/debian
content1

ctrl+D ,exit the connection

ssh root@192.168.31.43
ls  /home/debian
content2
```

Strange thing happens: content1 == content2 !
Two ip point to same one network card at the same time!!

Comment: Which distro?  We may need to see the configuration file in order to identify the issue. This file could have various names and be in different locations, depending on the distro.. Could be /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Check your configuration. Apparently one (43) is configured with DHCP and one (42) is statically configured.

Comment: Other IPd seem for virtualization/containers, not for you network card

Comment: lxcbr0 is the bridge between your machines eth0 interface and the Android container using the anbox0 device. This allow your machine and Android container to access the internet . See near the bottom of the following url: "https://wiki.debian.org/LXC/SimpleBridge" to see what your /etc/network/interface file should look like for eth0 once the bridge is setup. For the Android in a box,  see "https://anbox.io/".

Comment: Your `/etc/network/interfaces` says you get IP addresses via DHCP. So debug your DHCP process, start with checking the logs. If your DHCP server thinks it needs to assign two IP addresses to your machine, then you'll get two ... and yes, they'll act identically from the outside. Though usually one is preferred when making connections from that machine.

Comment: 1. Could you show the output of `ifconfig -a` (I know it's deprecated, but I am much more familiar with it)? 2. Could you show the files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` and the content of those files (if any)?